JNI Error when instrumenting with OpenTelemetry
I am running this code:
java -javaagent:/path/to/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -jar /path/to/my/project/out/artifacts/project_jar/project.jar 

While meaning to instrument the code in my project and retrieve some execution data (local vars, their values etc). But I am getting this error:
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:297)
.
.
.
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused


I am running the project with maven, Java 17, using IntelliJ, and trying to use OpenTelemetry as the java agent.
Commands java -version and javac -version both return 17.
Attaching other agents (e.g. jacoco) seems to work. Whether or not I specify the target -jar makes no difference and returns the same error.
Not sure how best to tackle this error next. Any advise will be appreciated.

Are you doing something like using Maven or Gradle to build a shaded jar file?  See Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes exception while trying to run jar file

If you are doing that and the signed jar file is Bouncy Castle, you can't remove the signatures.  Java crypto providers are required to be from signed jar files.  So you can't put Bouncy Castle into an uber jar file.

Thank you @AndrewHenle, you were right, filtering dependencies did not change the errror. However it seems to have been fixed by modifying the artifacts for the project - I removed all current deps from the application jar and added only those from 'Available Elements' tab. I was adding and removing other dependencies before this so that is probably what messed it up.
